# Java: How to Simulate a Scenario to, not to respond to a Post request

Tags: java, rest, httpconnection

I have a Web Service, which accepts Requests and send Responses back.
But I want to Simulate a Scenario, where I get a request, but I choose not to respond to it.

Comment: send a response 204 from the service

Comment: Do you not want to send a HTTP response or do you want like an empty response (see @RahulSingh comment)? You must send a HTTP response to the client if you choose to accept the request. However, you may be able to reject the request, but not on HTTP level.

Comment: You may want to look at mocking frameworks, such as [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/)

Comment: I don't want to send any response. Essentially I Want to generate a scenario pragmatically where I accept a request and then there is network failure.

Comment: @sumedhlam you want to terminate the connection when the user sends any request for that service is that so ?

Comment: @rahulSingh Yes, that's what I am looking into.

Comment: @sumedhlam make use of interceptors then , check for that particular pattern in the url and then donot even make a call to the service just redirect or do nything

Comment: check this link might help 

http://javatech-blog.blogspot.com/2015/04/jax-rs-interceptors-example.html